# What algorithm is used to compute a “bit that is two places to left of least significant bit in binary expansion of $n$” in the OEIS sequence A086483?

Tags: algorithms, binary

Let $Q$ denote the sequence [A086483](https://oeis.org/A086483):

> Bit that is two places to left of least significant bit in binary expansion of n.
>
> For n = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 the binary expansions are 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000 and the values of a(n) are respectively 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.

What algorithm is used to compute $Q$?

The sequence is $$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, \ldots$$

I constructed a list of binary expansions of integers:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
...
```

But I cannot seem to understand which column allows to obtain $000001010010\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's confusingly worded, indeed. I believe it's the *$\color{red}{bit}$ that is two places to the left of the least significant* ***non-zero*** *bit in the binary expansion of n*.

$$
\color{darkgray}{
0\,0\;\;0\,0\,0\,\color{red}{0}
\\ 0\,0\;\;0\,\color{red}{0}\,0\,\color{black}{1}
\\ 0\,0\;\;\color{red}{0}\,0\,\color{black}{1}\,0
\\ 0\,0\;\;0\,\color{red}{0}\,1\,\color{black}{1}
\\ 0\,\color{red}{0}\;\;0\,\color{black}{1}\,0\,0
\\ 0\,0\;\;0\,\color{red}{1}\,0\,\color{black}{1}
\\ 0\,0\;\;\color{red}{0}\,1\,\color{black}{1}\,0
\\ 0\,0\;\;0\,\color{red}{1}\,1\,\color{black}{1}
\\ \color{red}{0}\,0\;\;\color{black}{1}\,0\,0\,0
\\ 0\,0\;\;1\,\color{red}{0}\,0\,\color{black}{1}
\\ 0\,0\;\;\color{red}{1}\,0\,\color{black}{1}\,0
}
$$

Comment: Yes, this interpretation is plausible. I would expect such sequence to start with $n=1$ because the least significant non-zero bit does not exist for $n=0.$

Comment: @lyricallywicked It starts at $n=0$, if you look at the linked [table](https://oeis.org/A086483/b086483.txt). Guess the bit two places left of nowhere is assumed to be $0$ ;-)